# How to create a package with support for both flutter and dart at the same time

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to build a package for Flutter and Dart, but I don't have any previous experience with package development. I am not sure how to create the package. Should I use

```
flutter create --template=package
```

or

```
dart create -t package
```

I want support for both Flutter and Dart.

I looked at the Flutter documentation on creating packages, but I couldn't understand if it would create a package with Flutter only support, or both Flutter and Dart support.

Comment: Flutter is built on Dart.  A Flutter app can use any Dart package as long as that package doesn't use `dart:mirrors` or platform-specific libraries (such as `dart:html`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use the following command to check if your package meets all the requirements to publish the package.

```
dart pub publish --dry-run
```

Once you are sure that your package is ready to deploy on pub dev run this command:

```
dart pub publish
```

Comment: Will the package be published with support for both flutter and dart using this?

Comment: yes if you code your package with an only dart. you can also view your package availability on pub dev in a few minutes after publishing.